# How to set Manually Authenticate User with Spring boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I Created Spring boot application with SSO login. I have used saml.xml file for it. After SSO login i called `getAuthentication()` method it will return `annonymousUser`
every time. I want to get SSO Logged User details.

```
Principal principal = 
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Security configuration class look like following :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator").authenticated();
    http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/assets/logout.html");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make user login into spring security like below.

```
public void login(HttpServletRequest req, String user, String pass) { 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq
      = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass);
    Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);

    SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    sc.setAuthentication(auth);
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);
}
```

Refer [manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security](https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security)

Comment: how can i get username and password? i hve used sso.

Comment: @bhagyaperera create a custom class implementing `Authentication` instead of using `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` then